# Oracle database questions tagging

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, oracle

I've noticed [oracle11gr2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle11gr2) on question [Can a Wallet be used with SQL Developer? How?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175/119), and probably there will appear the like. Does it make sense to have tag synonyms so that the following tags will automatically be substituted with [oracle-db-11g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-db-11g):

- [oracle11gr2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle11gr2)
- [oracle-11g-r2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r2)
- [oracle-11g-r-2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r-2)
- [oracle-11g-release-2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-release-2)
- yadda yadda

Answer (score 4):

I suggest keeping it simple. The [Oracle tag wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) is a good example. A [similar page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/oracle/info) needs to be created here.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not -- my understanding is that tag synonyms all show up as valid options.  What we likely need to do instead is decide on a format the community prefers (I personally like `oracle-11g-r2`, and then pre-define all major release from each vendor, so we don't have people creating them.

(if someone does create one that's not of the standard format, a moderator (once we have them) can create the correct version, then use the tag merge tool to replace all of the bad tags with the correctly formatted one)

Comment: Actually we have 9 moderators, not specialized on dba.se but they can but these cleanup tasks for now.

Comment: I like the one you chose over the others. Hyphens break it up.

Comment: AFAIK tag synonyms according to [Privileges – Create Tag Synonyms](http://dba.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) help to save us from manual work on renaming incorrect tags to something more useful. I could get you wrong though.

Comment: @Yasir : yes, but the way they're implemented, they show up as a valid entry when someone's typing in a tag ... so it's useful for terms that aren't similar (so as you type, you find the other synonym) for what's effectively different spellings, it'll clutter up the input, and make it obnoxious to select between different versions, as there are half a dozen of each.

Comment: I see. Haven't experienced with them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my thoughts: The main tag ought to be:

- [oracle-11g-r2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r2)

The synonyms can be

- [oracle11gr2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle11gr2)
- [oracle11g-r2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle11g-r2)
- [oracle11g-r-2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle11g-r-2)
- [oracle-11g-r-2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r-2)
- [oracle-11g-release2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-release2)
- [oracle-11g-release-2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-release-2)

The same can be replicated across other Vendors/products.

Comment: I don't think that there needs to be "17" tags as synonyms. Just pick one and go for it. SO doesn't have c-sharp and C# and c# and C-sharp and c-sharp-3 and c-sharp-4 ... don't do the same here.